# drawer icon not left aligned and launcher icon not showing

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I've just tried to copy from this code;
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer

But I couldn't get launcher icon and drawer lines are not left aligned.

Here is my MainActivity ,I have no idea how to correct this.

[image: icon]

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.nsm.onur.nkys.adapter.NavDrawerItem;
import com.nsm.onur.nkys.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new PersonelIp();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment=new PersonelIp();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your app theme in `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: here app theme from manifest 
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: So what is the parent of the `AppTheme` under `values/styles.xml` ?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change parent of the `AppTheme` from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Comment: I tried that, but there are 2 problems.
1- I can't use this with min. api 8
2- With an android 4.4.2 device, I got this error;"Unable to start activity java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Comment: 1. To resolve first problem, change parent of the `AppTheme` to `Theme.Light.DarkActionBar`. 2. To resolve second problem, change `extends ActionBarActivity` to `extends Activity` in your `MainAcitivty` definition.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really confused. I've used ActionBarActivity because it is the only solution I could find for getSupportActionBar() .  If I use "extends Activity", I can't use getSupportActionBar, right?

Comment: Yes. If you want to support old versions, you should check http://actionbarsherlock.com/.

Comment: With "actionbarsherlock", it's better. Thank you