# Android drawer App icon not showing up - Incompatibility between Theme.AppCompat.Light and ActionBarActivity:

Tags: icons, themes, drawer, incompatibility, android-actionbaractivity

I'm trying to implement the Navigation Drawer on my app extending ActionBarActivity and using Theme.AppCompat.Light. the screen is like the one in this post  [drawer icon not left aligned and launcher icon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803884/drawer-icon-not-left-aligned-and-launcher-icon-not-showing)

The App Icon doesn't show up and the ic_drawer icon is not correctly aligned. I've seen posts with the same problem but none of them got a response that I could use.

I've already spent a week on this issue with no results.

Thank you in advance.

Bellow is the code:

```
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
//For app icon control for nav drawer
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

    mNavigationDrawerItemTitles= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[3];
    drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_camera, "My Pets");
    drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_drawer, "Married");
    drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_help, "Help");

    //Pass the list of drawer items to DrawerItemCustomAdapter
    DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_listview_item_row, drawerItem);

    //Set the adapter
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Set the item click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    //Set properties for proper title display
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    //Add the app icon control code
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
    ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    //getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new MyPetListFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new MyPetMarriedFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MyPetMarriedFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_navigation_drawer, menu);
    //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(true);
    return true;
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_help).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

   if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
   }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_help:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Help Pressed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

@Override
//This is really needed for changing titles.
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}`
```

And the styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/blue</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/myToolbarStyle</item>
    <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/myToolbarNavigationButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/darkbrown</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="background">@color/darkbrown</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkblue</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>

<style name="myToolbarNavigationButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
</style>

<style name="myToolbarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabText"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkred</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>



<style name="Text.Small" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/brownText</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>

<style name="Text.Small.Black" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="Text.Medium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/brownText</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="Text.Big" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/brownText</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>

</resources>
```